# saving dataset to cassandra using java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to save a dataset to cassandra db using java spark.
I'm able to read data into dataset successfully using the below code

```
Dataset<Row> readdf = sparkSession.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.option("keyspace","dbname")
.option("table","tablename")
.load();
```

But when I try to write dataset I'm getting **IOException: Could not load or find table, found similar tables in keyspace**

```
Dataset<Row> dfwrite= readdf.write().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.option("keyspace","dbname")
.option("table","tablename")
.save();
```

I'm setting host and port in sparksession
The thing is I'm able to write in overwrite and append modes but not able to create table

Versions which I'm using are below:
spark java 2.0
spark cassandra connector 2.3

Tried with different jar versions but nothing worked
I have also gone through different stack overflow and github links

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the exact error stack trace

Comment: read.write(). is wrong right is it typo

Comment: Ioexception: could not load or find table tablename

Comment: `describe tables;` has the table/keyspace  information ?` have you checked ? some where you are doing silly mistake is what i feel

Comment: Checked that but there is no table created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `write` operation in Spark doesn't have a mode that will automatically create a table for you - there are multiple reasons for that. One of them is that you need to define a primary key for your table, otherwise, you may just overwrite data if you set incorrect primary key.  Because of this, [Spark Cassandra Connector provides a separate method to create a table based on your dataframe structure](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/14_data_frames.md#creating-a-new-cassandra-table-from-a-dataset-schema), but you need to provide a list of partition & clustering key columns.  In Java it will look as following (full code is [here](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/spark/TableCreate.java)):

```java
DataFrameFunctions dfFunctions = new DataFrameFunctions(dataset);
Option<Seq<String>> partitionSeqlist = new Some<>(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(
          Arrays.asList("part")).seq());
Option<Seq<String>> clusteringSeqlist = new Some<>(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(
          Arrays.asList("clust", "col2")).seq());
CassandraConnector connector = new CassandraConnector(
          CassandraConnectorConf.apply(spark.sparkContext().getConf()));
dfFunctions.createCassandraTable("test", "widerows6",
          partitionSeqlist, clusteringSeqlist, connector);
```

and then you can write data as usual:

```java
dataset.write()
   .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
   .options(ImmutableMap.of("table", "widerows6", "keyspace", "test"))
   .save();
```

Comment: dfFunctions.createCassandraTable("test","widerows6",partitionSeqlist,clusteringSeqlist,connector) is giving ioexception failed to open native connection to Cassandra at 127.0.0.1 :9042 exception

Comment: your spark job doesn't point to Cassandra - check https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md